# in postgres how to select items that have a dupe across two columns

Tags: postgresql, group-by

My data looks like this:

```
queryable_type   queryable_id 
User             1 
User             2
User             2
```

I'd like to return dupes so that my result would look like this:

```
queryable_type  queryable_id count 
User            2            2
```

I'm assuming some multiple group by but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a most basic `group by` query:

```
select queryable_type, queryable_id, count(*)
from the_table
group by queryable_type, queryable_id 
having count(*) > 1
```